# Oscommerce multiple rates for each product based on country US / UK

Tags: php, mysql, oscommerce

Im new to OS-commerce [version 2.3] i have to implement 2 rates for each product based on the country US and UK. [currently title have option ]

If the user is from US - The product rate should says ex $ 8.5

If the user is from UK - The same above product rate should says ex Euro 5.00

The Site / DB are remain same[same domain] . Is there any plugin there to implement

Thanks,

Edvin.

Comment: As someone who lives in the UK, I'm far more used to paying for things in US$ then in €.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to set the currency rates accordingly. For example, if you in the US and product A cost $8.00 - you would need to add a new currency for the UK being the Euro - if not already added - then set the value so that when a customer changes the currency using the currency box on the front end from USD to Euro - the product price will update automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and i dont find any box to add euro currency value in admin while adding product can you provide sample website or some document link please. It will be more thankful..:)

Comment: First of all login to your admin section, (just by the way, you do fail to mention which version of oscommerce you using) - you will see your menu on the left hand side - its starts off at the top with Configuration, Catalog, Modules, Customers etc - you should also see the word "Localization" - well click on that -Once you've done that - you will see the very first menu item is called "Currencies" then Click on that.  You will be able to see what currencies you have and also have the ability to add a new currency.